# Handling unicode symbols in Java regex

Tags: java, regex, parsing, regex-greedy

My task is to parse integer value from a string with number and some text. Number could be formatted using different locales:

```
15 000 km
15,000 km
15.000 km
```

I have a solution:

```
(\d+[[\s\.,]?\d+]*)
```

works for above examples.
But as a edge case there is a special input wit code 160 instead of regular space (code 32):

```
15 000 km
```

How this could be solved using regex implementation in java?

Fiddle to it out: http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/5d8dd002-fe68-40c3-bf82-42e8574a2f5c

Ideally I would a like a general solution which will work any non-printable character.

Comment: ASCII code 160 is an a with an acute accent. Not sure how you are even receiving that.

Comment: Do you know the locale at the time of parsing the input? If yes you could use a different approach instead of a catch-all regex. As an example, you could use the strategy pattern and use a parser for that specific syntax for that locale

Comment: If you have hard spaces, just make sure you are using a Unicode aware `\s`. See http://ideone.com/jrligF where `\s` is used without the `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag.

Comment: How about something simple like `(\d+[\s.,\xA0]?\d+)`

Comment: http://ideone.com/jKXQy2 using `(\d+[\s.,\xA0]?\d+)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS`  flag to make your `\s` Unicode aware:

```
String pattern = "(?U)\\d+[\\s.,]?\\d+";
                  ^^^
```

See [Java demo](http://ideone.com/WWEOmo):

```
String value1 = "15 000 km\n15,000 km\n15.000 km\n15 000 km";
String pattern1 = "(?U)\\d+[\\s.,]?\\d+";
Pattern ptrn = Pattern.compile(pattern1);
Matcher matcher = ptrn.matcher(value1);
while (matcher.find())
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
```

Output:

```
15 000
15,000
15.000
15 000
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you include the additional separator (`\u00a0`)?

`(\d+(?:[\s.,\u00a0]?\d+)*)`

Compiling with the `UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` flag will make `\s` match, but there is a warning that it might be slower; you'd have to test to see if it matters on your input.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this simple regex that would match any 2 numbers separated by 0 or more non-digits i.e. `\D`:

```
\d+\D*\d+
```

In Java:

```
String regex = "\\d+\\D*\\d+";
```

`\D` will match any non-digit including any unicode character as well.

[Your Updated Demo](http://java-regex-tester.appspot.com/regex/dce23232-40aa-49c9-b803-4e8566b00981)

Comment: I thought about this kind of solution, but this won't work for:
15km
15 km
15 000 000 km